# How to convert the following line of plain JS to jQuery version 3.1.1?

Tags: jquery, css

What's the jQuery 3.1.1 version of this plainJS line:

```
expandDiv.style.width = Math.min(Math.max(scrollAndSpeed, 20), 95) + "%";
```

Comment: I don't see anything specifically jquery about this code, it looks as though expandDiv may have been captured from a previous $('*') call but I can't tell

Comment: oh, my mistake, I'm editing my question

Comment: Got you now :) cheers

Comment: see if this helps http://api.jquery.com/width/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may do the trick, need to add your own element selector

```
$('yourselectorhere').css({
    width: Math.min(Math.max(scrollAndSpeed, 20), 95) + "%"
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure where `scrollAndSpeed` is coming from

Comment: Thank you, works perfect! :) It's there to define the speed of the transition between 20 to 95% width. The function is triggered onScroll